# check existance of nested property in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and need to check for a nested property. I was told that I can use `.hasOwnProperty()` method. Here is the nested object chain and I'm interested in checking whether the property bool exists for the object query that is inside this nested hash.

```
 if(main_hash.query.filtered.query.hasOwnProperty("bool")){
      // do stuff
 }
```

I want to **make sure that `hasOwnProperty()` is called on the nested query object**, NOT the top level main_hash. Is that how hasOwnProperty will work?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` checks in the object on which is called: `main_hash.query.filtered.query`.

Comment: there will be no ambiguity with object notation...regardless of similar property names in the tree, will still only return the one you are pointing at

Comment: You're checking whether that `….query` object has an own `.bool` property. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: yes correct. So I guess my code here is correct

Comment: Would you have also wondered about this if you wrote `var query = main_hash.query.filtered.query; if(query.hasOwnProperty("bool")) { ... }` instead? It would be terrible if this would behave differently...

Comment: This would have been very easy to test without the need for the question.

Comment: No it's not that easy. Basically I'm still having trouble with this. Lets say instead of "bool" string passed to `hasOwnProperty` I pass a variable to it that contain's bool. But the variable's name is actually the thing I'm trying to check exists in the query object?